# How to parse only the children where attribute = foo from xml using android.sax?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I have an some data stored in an xml file like so:

```
<group name="example">
    <article name="foo">
        <content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</content>
        <link>
            <title>Lipsum</title>
            <url>http://www.lipsum.com/feed/html</url>
        </link>
    </article>
    <article name="bar">
        <content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</content>
        <link>
            <title>Google</title>
            <url>http://www.google.com</url>
        </link>
    </article>
</group>
```

Say I want to parse the specific article where `name="foo"` in android. I've been using the android.sax package so far, but I can't figure out if it even has this capability. Or if there's an alternative way to do this, I'd appreciate the help.

**EDIT:**
This is the code I have so far. I feel like I'm missing something. The problem is it's adding information from ALL of the articles instead of just the specific one that I want.

```
public Article parse(final String articleTitle) {
    RootElement root = new RootElement("learning");

    Element group = root.getChild("group");

    final Element article = group.getChild("article");

    article.setStartElementListener(new StartElementListener() {

        @Override
        public void start(Attributes attributes) {
            if (attributes.getValue("name").equals(articleTitle)) {
                currentArticle = new Article();
                currentArticle.setTitle(articleTitle);
                setupArticle(currentArticle);
            }
        }

        private void setupArticle(final Article currentArticle) {

            article.getChild("content").setEndTextElementListener(
                    new EndTextElementListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void end(String body) {
                            currentArticle.setContent(body);
                        }

                    });


    Context context = Application.getAppContext();
    InputStream raw;

    try {
        raw = context.getAssets().open("learning_articles.xml");
        Xml.parse(raw, Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return currentArticle;
```

Comment: [Android XML SAX Parser Example](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact answer, but when I use Groovy (which is capable of using sax) I did something similar to what is done here:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg05199/

I haven't personally done it with Android, but seeing how Android, Java, and Groovy are relatively similar in syntax it shouldn't be too hard to find your answer from there!

By the way it has examples in both Java and Groovy ;) (Listing two might be where you are interested in)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `EndTextElementListener` for `<content>` elements at the moment the parser actually *parse* the parent (`<article>`) element. Simply set all Listeners before you call `Xml.parse()` method and add condition to everyone of them.

I would put it like this:

```
private static Article currentArticle;

public Article parse(final String articleTitle) {
RootElement root = new RootElement("learning");
Element group = root.getChild("group");
final Element article = group.getChild("article");

article.setStartElementListener(new StartElementListener() {

    @Override
    public void start(Attributes attributes) {
        if (attributes.getValue("name").equals(articleTitle)) {
            currentArticle = new Article();
            currentArticle.setTitle(articleTitle);
        } else {
            currentArticle = null;
        }
    }
});

article.getChild("content").setEndTextElementListener(
                new EndTextElementListener() {

     @Override
     public void end(String body) {
        if (currentArticle.getTitle().equals(articleTitle)) {
           currentArticle.setContent(body);
        }
     }

});

Context context = Application.getAppContext();
InputStream raw;

try {
    raw = context.getAssets().open("learning_articles.xml");
    Xml.parse(raw, Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

return currentArticle;
```

Or if you want to parse multiple Articles, add `currentArticle` to the `List` at the end of `<article>` element and return whole Collection instead of just one object.